# How to apply a delta Euler angle after a set of Euler angles while maintaining revolutions?

Tags: linear-transformations, rotations, quaternions

I'm not a mathematician so I will try to explain this as best I could.

I have an application where transforms store rotations $R$ using Euler angles $Rx$, $Ry$ and $Rz$. The user is able to repeatedly apply a delta rotation $D$ after $R$.

The way I currently do it is by converting to quaternions and back:

- $q_R = f(R)$
- $q_D = f(D)$
- $q = q_R * q_D$
- $R = f^{-1}(q)$

Now this seems to works, with the caveat that I lose the revolutions in $D$ if it represents rotations greater than 360 degrees. So my questions are:

1. Does what I'm doing make sense or is there a better way?
2. How can I keep the revolutions in the resulting Euler angles?

**Note: I am using Euler angles because they are easier for users to understand and manipulate. Also, I need them for animation interpolations that describe rotations with more than 360 degrees. Something that I cannot do with Quaternions.**

Comment: It seems like you already understand why quaternions are not appropriate - they can’t represent rotations of over 360°, and simply revert to the principal angle. The question is, what are you trying to achieve? Do you wish to preserve the “big angle” information of the rotation after you apply it? In which case you cannot afford to convert to quaternions, or at least you must store that information in an auxiliary structure.

Comment: If I understand your intention properly, it might be worth storing the Euler angles and only converting to quaternions and composing those rotations when you need to apply them to an object/vector?

Comment: I need a way to accumulate the angles so that the rotations are successive. So I cannot just do R + D. That's why I'm converting to a Quaternion here.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the only way to do this is to store the sequence of rotations $D_1, D_2, \dotsc$. You can't just store an angle because you're working in 3D and "cumulative angle" just doesn't make sense in general, and you can't store anything that represents a rotation directly because rotations don't care about the "intermediate" steps between "rotated" and "unrotated".

Comment: If you want to interpolate a single rotation through cumulative angle $\theta$ and axis $v$ with quaternions, this is easy: represent $v$ as a unit imaginary quaternion, then $$ q(t) = e^{t\theta v/2} = \cos t\theta/2 + v\sin t\theta/2 $$ is your interpolated quaternion where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.